# PLSQL: Find invalid characters in a database column (UTF-8)

Tags: plsql, utf-8, ascii, invalid-characters

I have a text column in a table which I need to validate to recognize which records have non UTF-8 characters.
Below is an example record where there are invalid characters.

`text = 'PP632485 - Hala A - prace kuchnia Zepelin, wymiana muszli, montaô€„ª tablic i uchwytÃ³w na rô€„Šczniki, wymiana zamka systemowego'`

There are over 3 million records in this table, so I need to validate them all at once and get the rows where this text column has non UTF-8 characters.

I tried below:

- `instr(text, chr(26)) > 0` - no records get fetched
- `text LIKE '%Ã³%'` (tried this for a few invalid characters I noticed) - no records get fetched
- `update <table> set text = replace(text, 'Ã³', 'ó')` - no change seen in text

Is there anything else I can do?
Appreciate your input.

This is Oracle 11.2

Answer (score 1):

The characters you're seeing might be invalid for your data, but they *are* valid AL32UTF8 characters. Else they would not be displayed correctly. It's up to you to determine what character set contains the correct set of characters.

For example, to check if a string only contains characters in the US7ASCII character set, use the `CONVERT` function. Any character that cannot be converted into a valid US7ASCII character will be displayed as `?`.

The example below first replaces the question marks with string `'~~~~~'`, then converts and then checks for the existence of a question mark in the converted text.

```
WITH t (c) AS
(SELECT 'PP632485 - Hala A - prace kuchnia Zepelin, wymiana muszli, montaô€„ª tablic i uchwytÃ³w na rô€„Šczniki, wymiana zamka systemowego' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Just a bit of normal text' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Question mark ?' FROM DUAL),
converted_t (c) AS
(
SELECT 
  CONVERT(
  REPLACE(c,'?','~~~~~')
  ,'US7ASCII','AL32UTF8')
  FROM t
)
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(c,'?') > 0 THEN 'Invalid' ELSE 'Valid' END as status, c
FROM converted_t
; 

Invalid 
PP632485 - Hala A - prace kuchnia Zepelin, wymiana muszli, montao??? tablic i uchwyt??w na ro??Sczniki, wymiana zamka systemowego                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

Valid   
Just a bit of normal text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

Valid   
Question mark ~~~~~
```

Again, this is just an example - you might need a less restrictive character set.

--UPDATE--

With your data: it's up to you to determine how you want to continue. Determine what is a good target data set. Contrary to what I set earlier, it's not mandatory to pass a "from dataset" argument in the `CONVERT` function.

Things you could try:

1. Check which characters show up as '�' when converting from UTF8 at AL32UTF8

```
select * from G2178009_2020030114_dinllk
WHERE INSTR(CONVERT(text  ,'AL32UTF8','UTF8'),'�') > 0;
```

2. Check if the converted text matches the original text. In this example I'm converting to UTF8 and comparing against the original text. If it is different then the converted text will not be the same as the original text.

```
select * from G2178009_2020030114_dinllk
WHERE
CONVERT(text  ,'UTF8') = text;
```

This should be enough tools for you to diagnose your data issue.

Comment: Hi @Koen, thanks! this helped. 
The column data is written into an XML that is using UTF-8. The charset in the database is AL32UTF8, so I tried below.
`SELECT * FROM 
(WITH t (c) AS
(SELECT text FROM <table_name>), converted_t (c) AS
( SELECT  CONVERT(REPLACE(c,'�','?')  ,'AL32UTF8','UTF8') FROM t)
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(c,'?') > 0 THEN 'Invalid' ELSE 'Valid' END as status, c
FROM converted_t)
`

but the text mentioned in my question is showing as Valid.
How can I get it as Invalid?

I used � as it shows like that in the database, when CONVERT is used normally on my example text.

Comment: The ```CONVERT``` will show characters that are not in the destination character set as "?". So before you run convert, you need to replace the occurences of "?" with some other string - I used "~~~~~". This is because it the source string already conains a "?" it would be a false positive. In your statement you're doing ```replace( c,'�', '?')```. Replace that with ```REPLACE(c,'?','~~~~')``` instead.

Comment: Hi @Koen, thank you for the response. I tried the way you had mentioned, but it still doesn't seem to work.
I would also like to know, is there any way we can convert ANY character to UTF-8 (or something else) in Oracle without mentioning which charset it's being converted from?
Thanks!

Comment: All characters in your data *are* valid utf-8 characters. The code I showed illustrated how to convert to US7ASCII. I think the issue could be that your data was wrongly converted when it was created. No idea how to solve that. You cannot convert without knowing the source character set. Data in oracle is not saved as the actual character but as the character set representation of a string.

Comment: Hi @Koen, Please check https://imgur.com/a/DwO2zDf
My intention is to get the rows with � as Invalid instead of Valid.

Comment: Do ```REPLACE(c,'�','~~~~~')``` and ```WHEN INSTR(c,'�') > 0``` instead of what I posted earlier. I never get those characters so can't reproduce this...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. Still there is no change. 
https://imgur.com/y5eFche

Comment: If you would like to test further, 
here is the table creation sql: 
https://mega.nz/file/lp9RxQwJ#4WpYgrSfMbV-PbnlWAylnTBY7ZZ6avtBspEgX4TDflE
 and 
here is the insert sql for the data: https://mega.nz/file/880xmCJQ#8aiDmLGmqF6KNzRWI8HPh4eDByRGUKEsotZjISnzni0

thank you @Koen!

Answer (score 0):

As shown by previous comments, you can detect the issue in place, but it's difficult to automatically correct in place.
I have used https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/ to correct invalidly encoded characters in large files.
It guesses what the actual UTF8 character should be, and there are some controls on how it does this. For you, the problem is that you have to pull the data out, fix it, and put it back in.
So assuming you can get the data out to the file system to fix it, you can locate files with bad encodings with something like this:

```
find . -type f | xargs -I {} bash -c "iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 {} &>/dev/null || echo {}"
```

This produces a list of files that potentially need to be processed by ftfy.